Sub Area teams with identical board columns not syncing status
We use sub areas for our Sprint teams and have them all roll up to a "MOAB" type backlog that we use at the portfolio level.  This allows each team to view and manage their own backlog while giving our product team the ability to view and manage the backlog across team and align priority across teams.
Each the top level team and the sub teams each have their own board but all the columns, statuses and states are set up the same way.  All the teams align on how we update this information.
I am seeing that even though the columns are the same, if I update the column on the board at the team level (and see the correct board column status both on the team board and on the work item) that update is not visible on the portfolio level (top level team).  Even though that new column exists on the roll up board, the update is not visible and the work items continues to be displayed with in the old column status.
Is this expected?  Is there a setting or configuration that I missed?
Same issue in the other direction - if I make an update on the top level board the update is saved and visible on the work item (board column status) but is not displayed in the correct column on the sub-team board.
